# How to add parameter to Angular click function in ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript

This seems simple but it doesn't work.  I am making pagination for a list of things.  I have a pagination object that is defined as such:

in my models.ts:

```
export interface PageLink {
    displayText: string;
    pageNumber: number;
    status: string;
}
```

in my controller:

```
pageLinks: Array<PageLink>;
```

in my html:

```
<a *ngFor="let link of pageLinks" (click)="togglePage('test')" class="{{link.status}}">{{link.displayText}}</a>
```

This all works without blowing up, however my desire was to have the pageNumber parameter of the PageLink object put inside of the togglePage() function.  Doing this however:

```
<a *ngFor="let link of pageLinks" (click)="togglePage('{{link.pageNumber}}')" class="{{link.status}}">{{link.displayText}}</a>
```

Blows up.  When i do this i get very many lines of error in my console however the gist of the error is this:

**Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected**

Why does this happen, and how can i avoid it?

Note: This is Angular 5

Comment: Try this: `(click)="togglePage(link.pageNumber)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use interpolation. Whatever you have been passed to inside event attribute, it is going to evaluate against component context directly. The value of `pageNumber` would passed to `togglePage` function directly.

```
(click)="togglePage(link.pageNumber)"
```

Comment: That's it.  thanks.  I don't completely understand why this works but at least it does...  (I'll accept your answer as soon as the system lets me)

Answer (score 1):

This will work.No need to use interpolation

```
  <a *ngFor="let link of pageLinks" 
(click)="togglePage(link.pageNumber)" class="{{link.status}}">{{link.displayText}}</a>
```